# Windows Registry Key Check Fails in C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I am doing a java installation + version check but the installation check is failing.

I tried changing `JavaKey` and when I added a key that includes a space in it, it fails and returns false.

```cs
        bool checkIfJavaInstalled()
        {
            string JavaKey = "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\";
            bool installed = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(JavaKey) == null;
            return installed;
        }
```

I expect the result to be `true` but it returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. It was basically the architecture messing things up.

Old Code:

```cs
bool checkIfJavaInstalled()
{
    string JavaKey = "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\";
    bool installed = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(JavaKey) == null;
    return installed;
}
```

New code:

```cs
bool checkIfJavaInstalled()
{
    var regview = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432")))
    {
        regview = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry32;
    }
    string JavaKey = "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\";
    bool installed = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, regview).OpenSubKey(JavaKey) != null;
    return installed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are checking the wrong thing. You ask if the registry key at that path is null, and if it is, then Java is installed. I believe that you want to check that the key is *not* null. If they key is *not* null, then the Java registry key was found, and hence Java is installed.

Also, I want to mention that you need to dispose the intermediary key in the event that it is found. So, your code should look like:

```
RegistryKey key = null;
try
{
  key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\");
  if (key != null)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
finally
{
  if (key != null)
  {
    key.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I know I can change `key == null` to `key != null` but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For Java check I use this code. `is64` to specify which registry I want to check. Currently I call `CheckJavaIsInstalled` two times :)

```
public static bool CheckJavaIsInstalled(TaskLoggingHelper log) {
  if (CheckJavaIsInstalled(log, false) || CheckJavaIsInstalled(log, true))
    return true;
```

...

```
private static bool CheckJavaIsInstalled(TaskLoggingHelper log, bool is64) {

  try {
    using (var rk = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, is64 ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32)) {
      using (var subKey = rk.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment")) {
        if (subKey == null)
          return false;
        string currentVerion = subKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
        float version;
        if (float.TryParse(currentVerion, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out version)) {
          if (version < 1.8f)
            log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "Java version {0} older than 1.8", version);
        }
        else
          log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "Failed parse Java version {0} ", currentVerion);

      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    log.LogError("Java check failed");
    log.LogErrorFromException(ex);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```